# Выставить bounds такой же как и в более низком разрешении? Yandex Maps

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Делаю мобильную и десктопную версии карты.
1) Получаю bounds на мобильной версии и сохраняю на сервере
2) Получаю данные bounds с сервера на десктопной версии, выставляю их.
3) В итоге десктопная версия отображает область болбшую чем в мобильной версии.

Почему так ?
Как исправить.
Вот сами координаты:

```
0: (2) [55.683353030302506, 36.634511405071486]
1: (2) [56.17675350329516, 37.12889617069647]
```

Так создаю карту`this.myMap = new self.yaMap.Map(
      MAP_ID,
      {
        center: this.coordinates,
        zoom: self.zoom,
        controls: []
      },
      {
        yandexMapDisablePoiInteractivity: true,
        suppressMapOpenBlock: true,
        minZoom: MAP_MIN_ZOOM,
        maxZoom: MAP_MAX_ZOOM,
        restrictMapArea: [[84, -179, 999999], [-84, 179, 9999999]]
      }
    );`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

У меня после такого вызова:

```
myMap.setBounds([
    [55.683353030302506, 36.634511405071486],
    [56.17675350329516, 37.12889617069647]
], {
    checkZoomRange: true,
})
```

карта имеет примерно одинаковую видимую область и на десктопе, и на смартфоне (с поправкой на соотношение сторон экрана).
Вот тут есть пример с установкой центра и масштаба карты: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/Map-docpage/#method_detail__setBounds-param-bounds